# Group_by not functioning correctly when using filter and str_detect

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

Group_by doesn't seem to be functioning while i'm using filter. This is a simply reproduction of my data:

```
data = my_data_raw_quest 

user_id     question          dv
1            Allergies?        na     
1            food choice       left
2            Allergies?        yes, I hate gluten  
2            food choice       left        
3            Allergies?        allergic to soy 
3            food choice       left                   
4            Allergies?        na
4            food choice       left             
5            Allergies?        na
5            food choice       left            
6            Allergies?        Soy 
6            food choice       right          
7            Allergies?        na
7            food choice       right
```

when i run this code, it seems like group_by did not function correctly.

```
my_data_raw_quest_2 <- 
  my_data_raw_quest %>%
  dplyr::group_by(user_id) %>%
  filter(add = TRUE, is.na(dv)|
    !str_detect(dv, "(G|g)luten"))
```

This results in the following data set, when Instead I would like ALL responses from users that answered "gluten" to any question removed. Notice that line 3 is removed but not line 4.

```
user_id     question           dv
1            Allergies?        na     
1            food choice       left
2            food choice       left        
3            Allergies?        allergic to soy 
3            food choice       left                   
4            Allergies?        na
4            food choice       left             
5            Allergies?        na
5            food choice       left            
6            Allergies?        Soy 
6            food choice       right          
7            Allergies?        na
7            food choice       right
```

This is the table im trying to achieve

```
user_id     question           dv
1            Allergies?        na     
1            food choice       left
3            Allergies?        allergic to soy 
3            food choice       left                   
4            Allergies?        na
4            food choice       left             
5            Allergies?        na
5            food choice       left            
6            Allergies?        Soy 
6            food choice       right          
7            Allergies?        na
7            food choice       right
```

This code represents a better representative of all the data I have, I aim to keep ALL the columns. Al though in this code below there is no example of an answer containing gluten.

```
structure(list(session_id = c(53039, 53039, 53039, 53039, 53039, 
53039, 53047, 53047, 53047, 53047, 53047, 53047, 53050, 53050, 
53050, 53050, 53050, 53050, 53052, 53052, 53052, 53052, 53052, 
53052, 53054, 53054, 53054, 53054, 53054, 53054, 53055, 53055, 
53055, 53055, 53055, 53055, 53056, 53056, 53056, 53056), project_id = c(495, 
495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 
495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 
495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495
), quest_name = c("Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", 
"Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", 
"Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", 
"Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", 
"Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", 
"Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", 
"Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", 
"Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", 
"Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", 
"Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", 
"Sociodemographic"), quest_id = c(2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 
2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 
2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 
2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 
2189, 2189), user_id = c(46942, 46942, 46942, 46942, 46942, 46942, 
46946, 46946, 46946, 46946, 46946, 46946, 46947, 46947, 46947, 
46947, 46947, 46947, 46949, 46949, 46949, 46949, 46949, 46949, 
46950, 46950, 46950, 46950, 46950, 46950, 46951, 46951, 46951, 
46951, 46951, 46951, 46952, 46952, 46952, 46952), user_sex = c("male", 
"male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", 
"male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", 
"male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", 
"male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", 
"male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male"), user_status = c("test", 
"test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "guest", "guest", "guest", 
"guest", "guest", "guest", "guest", "guest", "guest", "guest", 
"guest", "guest", "guest", "guest", "guest", "guest", "guest", 
"guest", "registered", "registered", "registered", "registered", 
"registered", "registered", "guest", "guest", "guest", "guest", 
"guest", "guest", "guest", "guest", "guest", "guest"), user_age = c(23, 
23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 
22, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 58.9, 58.9, 58.9, 58.9, 58.9, 58.9, 
21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22), q_name = c("vegan", 
"religious", "religious influence", "food allergies", "Other", 
"Education", "vegan", "religious", "religious influence", "food allergies", 
"Other", "Education", "vegan", "religious", "religious influence", 
"food allergies", "Other", "Education", "vegan", "religious", 
"religious influence", "food allergies", "Other", "Education", 
"vegan", "religious", "religious influence", "food allergies", 
"Other", "Education", "vegan", "religious", "religious influence", 
"food allergies", "Other", "Education", "vegan", "religious", 
"religious influence", "food allergies"), q_id = c(92827394, 
92827395, 92827396, 92827397, 92831398, 92832133, 92827394, 92827395, 
92827396, 92827397, 92831398, 92832133, 92827394, 92827395, 92827396, 
92827397, 92831398, 92832133, 92827394, 92827395, 92827396, 92827397, 
92831398, 92832133, 92827394, 92827395, 92827396, 92827397, 92831398, 
92832133, 92827394, 92827395, 92827396, 92827397, 92831398, 92832133, 
92827394, 92827395, 92827396, 92827397), order = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4), dv = c("1", "Athetiesm", 
"none", "none", "none", "Undergraduate", "5", "Nope, Atheist", 
"None", "No, i am normal", "Money", "Undergraduate", "3", "Nope, Atheist", 
"None", "No", "No", "Postgraduate (masters)", "1", "Christianity", 
"None", "No", "Cost", "Postgraduate (masters)", "2", "Nope, Atheist", 
"none", "none", "less processed, cook fresh", "Undergraduate", 
"1", "Christianity", "None", "No", "Cost", "Postgraduate (masters)", 
"6", "Nope, Atheist", NA, NA), starttime = structure(c(1607440590, 
1607440590, 1607440590, 1607440590, 1607440590, 1607440590, 1607441663, 
1607441663, 1607441663, 1607441663, 1607441663, 1607441663, 1607441637, 
1607441637, 1607441637, 1607441637, 1607441637, 1607441637, 1607442744, 
1607442744, 1607442744, 1607442744, 1607442744, 1607442744, 1607442919, 
1607442919, 1607442919, 1607442919, 1607442919, 1607442919, 1607442998, 
1607442998, 1607442998, 1607442998, 1607442998, 1607442998, 1607443123, 
1607443123, 1607443123, 1607443123), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), endtime = structure(c(1607440643, 1607440643, 
1607440643, 1607440643, 1607440643, 1607440643, 1607441839, 1607441839, 
1607441839, 1607441839, 1607441839, 1607441839, 1607441714, 1607441714, 
1607441714, 1607441714, 1607441714, 1607441714, 1607442819, 1607442819, 
1607442819, 1607442819, 1607442819, 1607442819, 1607443041, 1607443041, 
1607443041, 1607443041, 1607443041, 1607443041, 1607443020, 1607443020, 
1607443020, 1607443020, 1607443020, 1607443020, 1607443148, 1607443148, 
1607443148, 1607443148), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
40L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2: Updated with semi-join**

After some thought and with your example data, I think the following should work. Note I tested it on the word "none" as I couldn't find gluten in the sample provided, so obviously change the pattern accordingly for your needs.

```
my_data_raw_quest %>% group_by(user_id) %>% 
# Select user_id and dv, then nest into list columns
  select(user_id,dv) %>% 
  summarise( dv = list(dv)) %>% 
# Find occurences of none in dv
mutate(none = map(dv, str_detect, pattern = "none"),
# filter out using a logical vector, replace NAs
none = !map_lgl(none, any),
none = replace_na(none,FALSE)
) %>% 
  filter(none) %>% 
# semi-join on user_id to return selected users only
    semi_join(y = ., x = my_data_raw_quest, by = "user_id")
```

**Edit 1: Nesting / Unnesting**

One way could be to nest the columns after grouping by user id, then map over a filtering sequence and unnesting again:

```
my_data_raw_quest %>% group_by(user_id) %>% 
# Nest into list columns
summarise(question = list(question), dv = list(dv)) %>% 
# Find occurences of gluten
mutate(gluten = map(dv, str_detect, pattern = "(G|g)luten"),
# filter out using a logical vector
gluten = !map_lgl(gluten, any)) %>% 
  filter(gluten) %>% select(-gluten) %>% 
# unnest
  unnest(c(question,dv))
```

Comment: Hello awaji98, thanks for the help:) this seems to work perfectly, al though now i realise that I did not identify what I needed correctly. 
This code deletes answers within "dv" that have NA values due to filter, i tried to counter this by including "filter(gluten | is.na(dv)) %>% but with no luck. 
Also, I have about 20 more columns that are not included, I'm just putting them in one by one into the code, but just for future is there a quicker way to make all the columns into a list?:) thanks again so much!!!!

Comment: wow awaji98 thank you so so so much!! I really appreciate your help and your second edit. The edit 2 worked perfectly after changing replace(none, FALSE) to "TRUE"). Thanks again, really appreciate it :D

Comment: Glad it worked! By the way, to list across all columns except user_id, you can use tidyr::nest. The following code should also work tested on the word cost: my_data_raw_quest %>% group_by(user_id) %>%   nest%>%  mutate(cost = !map_lgl(data,~{any(str_detect(.x$dv,regex("cost", ignore_case = TRUE)))}),         cost = replace_na(none,FALSE)) %>%     filter(cost) %>%     select(-cost) %>%     unnest(data)

Comment: ahh thank you again I will definitely use that in the future:)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
library(tidyr)

my_data_raw_quest %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = question, values_from = dv) %>% # Reshape to wide
  filter(str_detect(`Allergies?`, "(G|g)luten", negate = TRUE) | str_detect(`food choice`, "(G|g)luten", negate = TRUE)) %>% # Filter
  pivot_longer(c(`Allergies?`, `food choice`), names_to = "question", values_to = "dv") # Reshape back to original shape
```

By the way, I don't know what you were looking to achieve with `filter(add = TRUE, ...)`. `add` is not a valid argument for `filter()`.

Comment: Hey Phil, thanks so much for the reply! Unfortunately it hasn't worked due to me not giving a comprehensive example of my code. Here is my error " Error: Can't combine `session_id` <double> and `quest_name` <character>. " I have changed sesssion_id to numerical in hopes of it helping but there was no difference. I have included the code for my data in my original post in hopes that it helps. Thanks anyway:)

Comment: I've edited my code above, try it with that. Otherwise, I suggest removing the columns that you don't need for this operation and to only keep the data you shared here in order to reproduce.